# Does Generics give me some advantages in performance and pros and cons?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, architecture

i'm trying to generate some methods like below, add `crm` and `human resources`. But i want to write Crm,humanResources,SupplChain etc. (5-6 Modules) how to write below codes simple(Below codes is skeleton :))
i'd written without generics first and then i've written with generics. Second usage differs from first. 
1) Clear reading also managed and expendable
2) give me some performance advantages. No boxing and unboxing process

CAN YOU teach me pros and cons of generics WITH compare first and second usage?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace App.GenericsBaseClass.Diff
{

    // View : 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Crm().Add("Yapı Kredi");
            Console.Read();
            new HumanResources().Add("yusuf karatoprak");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

  // Business
    public class Crm : Customer
    {
        public override void Add(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is String)
            {
                base.Add(obj);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Customer Name must be string Format...");
            }
        }
    }

    public class HumanResources : Staff
    {
        public override void Add(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is string)
            {
                base.Add(obj);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Stuff Name must be string Format...");
            }

        }
    }

    // Dal
    public class Staff
    {
        public virtual void Add(object obj)
        {
            new Db.Staff().Save((string)obj);
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public virtual void Add(object obj)
        {
            new Db.Customer().Save((string)obj);
        }

    }
    // Model
    public class Db
    {

        public class Customer
        {
            public void Save(string Name)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Customer : {0} is saved",Name);
            }
        }

        public class Staff
        {
            public void Save(string Name)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Staff: {0} is saved", Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace App.GenericsInstadofBaseMethod
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Crm<string>().Add("Yapı Kredi");
            Console.Read();
            new HumanResources<string>().Add("yusuf karatoprak");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    // Business
    public class Crm<T> : Customer<T>
    {
        public override void Add(T obj)
        {
                base.Add(obj);
        }
    }

    public class HumanResources<T> : Staff<T>
    {
        public override void Add(T obj)
        {
                base.Add(obj);
        }
    }

    // Dal
    public class Staff<T>
    {
        public virtual void Add(T obj)
        {
            new Db<T>.Staff().Save(obj);
        }
    }

    public class Customer<T>
    {
        public virtual void Add(T obj)
        {
            new Db<T>.Customer().Save(obj);
        }

    }
    // Model

    public class Db<T> 
    {
        public class Customer
        {
            public void Save(T Name)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Customer : {0} is saved", Name.ToString());
            }
        }

        public class Staff
        {
            public void Save(T Name)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Staff: {0} is saved", Name);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this use of generics? It seems quite useless to me to have generic `Name`.

Comment: Should probably be `Customer<T>` and `Staff<T>` instead of `Db<T>`

Comment: If you want to save a string name, make your method take a string.  What's the point in creating an API contract that you can't actually fulfil?  The whole hierarchy of types is muddled due to the mixing of persistence concerns with an unnecessarily deep inheritance hierarchy.  I'd recommend taking a look at a decent ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from my post explaining some things about generics, your situation here doesn't look like it really requires them at all. You should instead add a property to your class.

```
public class Person {
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Customer : Person {

}
public class Staff : Person {
}

public class HumanResources : Staff {
}

public class Db {
  public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
  public List<Staff> Staff { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(){ 
  var db = new Db {
     Customers = new List<Customer> { },
     Staff = new List<Staff> { }
  };

  Db.Customers.Add(new Customer { Name = "Primary Customer" } );
  Db.Staff.Add(new Staff { Name = "Employee Prime" } );
  Db.Staff.Add(new HumanResources { Name = "Human Resource Manager" });
}
```

The generics should be used to insist on the type that goes in, not to actually control the data. The example you have isn't using generics in its real intended fashion.

In this example, you create a base class and then three sub-types, one of which inherits from another sub-type. So you have `Customer` and `Staff` as your two primary types that the `Db`, (assuming that is short for database) accepts.

The `Db` can take a List of `Customer`s and a list of `Staff`, since `HumanResources` is a type of `Staff` you can store them together. You could also add a `List<Person> People { get; set; }` and it would accept all of the types since they inevitably inherit from each other.

As for enforcing strings, that would be better done in your constructors.

```
public class Person { 
   public Person(string name) { 
      this.Name = name; }
   }

   public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

In this example, we are setting up the `Name` field so that it can be seen by everything, but only changed and set at creation (not really the best idea, but it demonstrates the point).

So now, you would add a new `Customer` like this ..

`Db.Customers.Add( new Customer ( "Ciel" ) );` or a new Staff... `Db.Staff.Add( new Staff( "Darin" ) );`.

Answer (score 3):

From what little I understand, most operations with Generics happen at the `IL` level, so there is not much of a performance hit, if any at all. All it does is force and check objects to be of a certain type. The biggest con is the understanding of contravariance and covariance. Here are some articles about it.

## Articles

[Using Variance in Interfaces for Generic Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465120%28VS.100%29.aspx)

[Covariance and Contravariance FAQ (.NET 4.0 Updated)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

### Pros

With generics, you get type-safety both in your runtime, and your design time. You are able to receive intellisense about your objects in real time as if they were hard-coded for a specific type. This is very useful when setting up both extension methods, and ...well pretty much everything else. In fact, since .NET 2.0, I do not even find myself using non-generic lists for anything anymore unless the type is just `object`

- Edit

> As others have pointed out, this prevents the need for unboxing.

### Cons

Because of the different natures of contra-variance and covariance, it can get confusing as to what is and is not acceptable in a generic at times. For instance, if you consider the following layout ..

```
interface IBase {
}

class Alpha : IBase {
}

class Beta : Alpha {
}

IList<IBase> ListOfObjects { get; set; }
```

This is confusing. Can you pass both `Alpha` and `Beta` objects into the list? When I tried it, you couldn't. But then the following worked..

```
IList<Alpha> ListOfObjects { get; set; }
```

It accepted both `Alpha` and `Beta` objects because `Beta` inherits `Alpha`

Take a look at some more information about contravariance and covariance [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx). It is very useful.

I have *never* noticed a performance hit from generics. However that does not mean they do not exist. However they are just plain objects, so I cannot see where there would be overhead. In general the compiler should not even let you run code where you are trying to add improper objects to a generic list, and it if does, then you've made a designer error somewhere, or are using `dynamics`, or running into an issue of contravariance vs. covariance. Though I do understand that some of this has changed with .NET 4.0.

Comment: actually not all that similar to templates. And what do you mean by "older C++ code"?

Comment: Terminology difference. My college professors showed us something in C++ that functioned slightly similar to generics a long time ago, and called them templates. I don't code in C++, so I do not know the actual term. I should have been more specific - I honestly do not even remember it enough to understand why I put that comment in there. Basically, you could establish a class that could accept any type and perform certain operations on them, regardless of the type.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the performance difference is significant.

What you really gain by using generics is compile-time checking for the types. It can prevent you from passing an object of the wrong type, for instance (using an `object` parameter would result in runtime errors in this case if you are expecting a specific type).

Comment: Generics allow you to avoid boxing for value types, whereas using `object` forces boxing.

Comment: I'll add that generics create the static versions of the methods at compile time - not runtime.  So there shouldn't be any impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

Generics is all about type safety imho. You get to write more robust code, since you get compile time errors instead of runtime trial&terror.

Boxing is a bonus, but you should not choose generics just to avoid boxing (which sounds like premature optimization).

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a very interesting video on the [Advantages and Disadvantages of using generics](http://venkatcsharpinterview.blogspot.com/2011/05/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using.html).